# Why does Perl system() corrupt the redirected path?

Tags: perl, unicode

I have the following command in a perl script I'm using:

```
system ("mycommand /home/tahoar/ไมโคร_tm-อังกฤษ-ไทย/giza.อังกฤษ-ไทย/อังกฤษ-ไทย.A3.final.part*>/home/tahoar/ไมโคร_tm-อังกฤษ-ไทย/giza.อังกฤษ-ไทย/อังกฤษ-ไทย.A3.final")
```

The command fails with this error:

```
sh: cannot create /home/tahoar/ไมโคร_tm-อัง��ฤษ-ไทย/giza.อัง��ฤษ-ไทย/อัง��ฤษ-ไทย.A3.final: Directory nonexistent
```

My troubleshooting has determined that "mycommand" is never executed. It also happens with a variety of other commands (mycommand1, mycommand2, etc). The command string is UTF-8. The intended output path already exists. I have set LC_ALL=C for other purposes. The same command runs correctly with Latin character in the path.

Why is the redirected output path being corrupted?

Comment: Do you have `use utf8` at the head of your program?

Answer (score 2):

I tried exactly the above command. If the directory is missing I get exactly the same error.
After a corresponding mkdir, everything seems to be fine.

The command is not run in your case, because perl starts a sh which first tries to set up your redirects and then start your command connected to the prepared redirects. - In your case sh fails to prepare the redirects and is therefore not able to start the actual command.

As you say "output path already exists" but perl says "Directory nonexistent" you both seem to talk about different paths.

Try to mkdir or ls the output path from within perl. Then you should be able to see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the 'sh' command is receiving the corrupted string. Another command in the Perl script calls "mkdir" and creates the correct output path. I believe the heart of the problem is why is Perl corrupting the string only when it occurs as a redirected output?

Comment: It does not. In perl it is just a string, which is given to sh. Perl has no idea that some part of the string is a redirection. There might only be some strange conversions breaking things

Comment: What happens when you do `mkdir $path; ls -la $path; echo test >$path/foo` from within perls system call? Is the path created correctly on the file system? is the echo able to write to that directory? If not something is really strange. ;)

Comment: Fair enough, but the Perl script uses system() to call "mycommand", which, by the way, is a Python script that does NOT call "sh" and never executes anyway. Perl terminates with the "sh" error. So, is there a way to configure Perl in its communications with "sh"? It's at that layer where the UTF-8 is breaking.

Comment: I tried to add `use utf8;` to the Perl script. It did not help. `system(mkdir $path)` works. `ls -la $path` works. `echo text>$path/foo` fails with "Directory nonexistent".

Comment: perl -we '$path="your/path";system "mkdir -p $path; ls -la $path; echo test >$path/foo; cat $path/foo"' - What happens? BTW: What OS are you on?

Comment: @michas: Firstly, please get a room. Secondly, please elaborate your comments so that others can understand your train of thought.